# Bilingual 404 page in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, http-status-code-404, multilingual

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32839796/7468901) for a functioning bilingual MVC4 site. I made 404 error page which is also bilingual, but when I enter a wrong link, either it goes to the English version or it shows the MVC stock 404 page. I tried many solutions, including both the solutions [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577151/creating-multilingual-not-found-page-in-mvc), but nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Successfully made it to work. Thanks to @r.vengadesh and the links I provided in the question. Anyway, here are the files and the modifications within...

**Global.asax:**

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.ClearError();
    var routeData = new RouteData();
    HttpContextBase currentContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
    var culture = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(currentContext).Values["culture"];
    routeData.Values["culture"] = culture;
    routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";

    if ((Context.Server.GetLastError() is HttpException) && ((Context.Server.GetLastError() as HttpException).GetHttpCode() != 404))
    {
        routeData.Values["action"] = "Index";
    }
    else
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        routeData.Values["action"] = "page404";
    }
    IController errorController = new ErrorController();
    HttpContextWrapper wrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);
    var rc = new System.Web.Routing.RequestContext(wrapper, routeData);
    errorController.Execute(rc);
}
```

And the **RouteConfig:**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultWithCulture",
            url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { culture = new CultureConstraint(defaultCulture: "en", pattern: "[a-z]{2}") }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { culture = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        // Catch-all route (for routing misses)
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Localized-404",
            url: "{culture}/{*url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "page404" },
            constraints: new { culture = new CultureConstraint(defaultCulture: "en", pattern: "[a-z]{2}") }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default-404",
            url: "{*url}",
            defaults: new { culture = "en", controller = "Error", action = "page404" }
        );
    }
}
```

Of course you need to have **ErrorController** with a page404 inside.

Answer (score 0):

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Do whatever you want to do with the error

            //Show the custom error page...
            Server.ClearError();
            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";

            if ((Context.Server.GetLastError() is HttpException) && ((Context.Server.GetLastError() as HttpException).GetHttpCode() != 404))
            {
                routeData.Values["action"] = "Index";
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle 404 error and response code
                Response.StatusCode = 404;
                routeData.Values["action"] = "NotFound404";
            }
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true; // If you are using IIS7, have this line
            IController errorsController = new ErrorController();
            HttpContextWrapper wrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);
            var rc = new System.Web.Routing.RequestContext(wrapper, routeData);
            errorsController.Execute(rc);
        }
```

And just create a **Error** controller and create **NotFound404** view whatever you entered in that above as a view you create that

It worked for me.

Comment: Tried this and again it goes to the default English 404 page. It doesn't stay in German. Only difference is: in the address bar nothing changes after the wrong URL is put, instead of showing ".....?aspxerrorpath=.....". Btw I can't see how does this code makes use of the culture part of the routing (localhost:xxxx/en/   and   localhost:xxxx/de/)