# Multi language, using Resources on server always gives server language

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multilingual, resx

**TL;TR:** Using multi language resources, class library keeps using server language instead if user decided language (url parameter).

*Environment: ASP.NET 4.5.2, Visual Studio 2015 RC.*

So I have pretty big website setup in multi language, using Resources. I have a separate project in my solution that only contains the `.resx` files for two languages. Default language is Dutch, second is English, so the resource files are named: `Resources.resx` and `Resources-en.resx`.

I determine the language by the url, I have a Localization attribute, it is added in the `FilterConfig` and is used in the MVC routing. (link below)

So website **example.com/** will give dutch, **example.com/en** will give english.

There are two more projects in the solution. One class library, one MVC application and the previous mentioned Language project.

This all works pretty well, I can call `Resources.Resources.xx` from every point I want. All models are inside the class library and they also have multi language `DataAnnotations` which work correctly in both languages, I can throw exceptions with multi language error message which also comes in the correct language.

Yet I have one issue (else I wasn't here, right?).

Based on selecting some products, additional costs are added to the shopping cart. These are dynamically added to the shopping cart and saved in the database. The description and title for these additional costs also use these resources, yet they always come in English (not the selected language!). This happens inside the class library, and depending on the server language, it uses that resource language.

Same goes for generating Invoices, where it also uses the Resources project, it as well always use the server language to determine what text to get. When I test locally (on a computer language set to Dutch) it gives the additional costs description in dutch and invoice description in dutch as well, but when choosing the english language, it still gives everything in dutch, so it keeps the server language.

So you want some code?

Used [this blog post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/setup-a-multi-language-website-using-asp-net-mvc/#How_to_serve_the_properlanguage_to_each_Request) to get the localization setup (not advertising here, not mine)

So on every request, this code is executed:

```
            CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo(lang);//nl-NL or en-EN
            info.NumberFormat = numberInfo;
            info.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
            info.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = info;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = info;
```

Little bit of code:

```
AdditionalCost adcost = new AdditionalCost()
{
    //unrelated stuff here
    title = Resources.Resources.additionalCostsDepositTitle,
    description = Resources.Resources.additionalCostsDepositDescription,
    //unrelated stuff here
};
```

when I get the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` it is `nl-NL` even though the entire website is in english (because the current url is example.com/en).

Hope anyone got some experience with setting up your class libraries to use multi language as well (for setting database attributes). I have shared hosting, so I cannot control the server, but it has to be multi language depending on the users choice anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and  `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` are correctly set _before_ you enter the code that you pasted?

Comment: See updated answer, Current Culture is server language.

Comment: maybe the bug is how you determine `lang`?

Comment: For the website it is determined by the URL, how asp.net determines it when using such Resources? i dont know

Comment: The thread setting looks ok (assuiming its on `Application_BeginRequest` or similar`, the bit we can't see is how you set the `lang` variable.

Comment: The lang variable is set by the url Language parameter, if the url is example.com/en it is converted to en-GB, and when debugging that code, it hits on every get or post request.

Comment: My bet: you're using multiple threads and you only set the culture for the current thread. Try this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifyable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is unclear from your question *where* the code you pasted is being run.

Comment: Note that you should not use `ActionFilterAttribute` as the post suggests because this will not enable localization in the model binder. You should use `IAuthorizationFilter` as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764989/asp-net-mvc-5-culture-in-route-and-url#32839796).

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, @Gusman you were right, it was executed on another thread.