# How to set {city} in all the routes MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, marketplace

I am developing a marketplace application which is supposed to have different products and vendors which are mapped to different cities.
The idea is that I need to store the CurrentCity in context so that I can use it to construct urls, filter data, fetch delivery areas etc.
e.g.

```
www.mywebsite.com/cityA/listings
www.mywebsite.com/cityB/listings

www.mywebsite.com/cityA/cart
www.mywebsite.com/cityB/cart
```

Something like the MoonPig website (https://www.moonpig.com/uk/Gift/Flowers/)

Currently, I am passing the city as a parameter in almost all the controller methods and also storing it in a cookie.

Alternatively, I am also thinking of creating a BaseController and possibly inject it in the OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context).

But the problem with the first approach is that all the Action methods need to have "city" as a parameter and I need to have it in context for doing something like

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Listings", new {city = cityName})
```

If I use the second approach, then I don't think I'll get the urls which have city in them.

I am ideally looking for a solution with which I can inject a city parameter as Base route / segment in the MVC RouteDictionary so that all the Urls are generated accordingly (with @url helper).

Is this possible or is there a better way to tackle this problem?
Would really appreciate if someone can show me a direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the problem with the first approach is that all the Action methods need to have "city" as a parameter

This assumption is incorrect, since MVC automatically passes values from the current context when generating URLs, so there is no need to explicitly pass `city` as long as it is configured in the route and present in the URL. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764989/asp-net-mvc-5-culture-in-route-and-url#32839796) for how you can utilize this behavior for localization, which is similar to what you are doing.