# Default value for URL segment for all actions and not just root?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization

I am working on localizing my static website in multiple languages. I've already added two resource (.resx) files, `Strings.resx` and `Strings.es.resx`.

I have a RouteConfig, like this:

```
var language = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    constraints: new { lang = @"(\w{2})|(\w{2}-\w{2})" },
    defaults: new { lang = language, controller = "app", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I also have the following Filter setup:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new LocalizationAttribute("en"), 0);
    }
}
```

Which uses this attribute:

```
public class LocalizationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private string mDefaultLanguage = "en";

    public LocalizationAttribute(string defaultLanguage)
    {
        mDefaultLanguage = defaultLanguage;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string lang = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] ?? mDefaultLanguage;
        if (lang != mDefaultLanguage)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("ERROR: Invalid language code '{0}'.", lang));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I navigate to my home page with this, it defaults to the English language, and the URL looks like `http://example.com/`.

When I navigate to any other action, it changes the URL to: `http://example.com/en-us/register`, for example. If I remove the `en-us` from the URL, and just make it `http://example.com/register`, I get a `404`.

Note, if I change the URL to `http://example.com/es/` and `http://example.com/es/register`, it works as expected. I'd just like the default to be English, even when `en` or `en-us` isn't supplied.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 5 culture in route and url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764989/asp-net-mvc-5-culture-in-route-and-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add more than one route mapping since your defaults are sets to en

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {controller = "Home or app", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        constraints: new { lang = @"(\w{2})|(\w{2}-\w{2})" },
        defaults: new { lang = language, controller = "app", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: Two things to make this the answer. First: rename one of the routes to something other than `Default`, since two route can't have the same name. Second, move the catch-all `Default` route below the localization route so the localization route is attempted to be used first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an additional route without the language in the url, and then specifying the language in the defaults? Will need to be put in after the first route to prevent it matching everything.

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { lang = "en", controller = "app", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```