# ASP.NET MVC 5 culture in route and url only routing to english

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization

I just follow the steps in the following link
[ASP.NET MVC 5 culture in route and url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764989/asp-net-mvc-5-culture-in-route-and-url#32839796)

I just followed the instructions to create localized website with arabic as default language "ar" and english as second language . it works but it seems it doesn't set the culture in the thread and keeps showing the english page with english resources . I tried to debug and follow the code line by line it doesn't pass through OnAuthorization !!!

and this is my code in global to set

```
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(new GlobalFilterCollection()); 
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); 
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); 
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);      
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

Shall I set attribute somewhere ?? because on authorization is not running at all

Need assistance . Thanks

Comment: Even when I type 'ar' as culture paramter in the url it keeps showing the english resource. the 'ar' is the default

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the global filters correctly. They need to be added to a static collection that MVC then reads.

### Change:

```
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(new GlobalFilterCollection());
```

### To:

```
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
```

Comment: Based on this I have an issue with routing in the following link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39141344/action-routelink-doesnt-take-prefix-url-for-culture