# How to handle multiple language in MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing, multilingual

I've set up my application so that the contents are read from different RESX files, according to the pattern that the router recognizes. Every page is accessible in a certain language depending on the first part of the URL.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Localization",
  url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", ...
);
```

When I'm testing with no specification, I get to the English version of my Lingo.REXS and when I put in *se*, I get to the Swedish version, i.e. Lingo.se.RESX. Everything's fine this far.

However, I'm not sure how to let the user control the setting of the language. I don't want it to be automatic nor assumed based on the browser's settings, geo-data etc. I basically want three flags (img controls) that **somehow magically** set that user (or at least that browser session) to be routable with the prefix corresponding to the language of the flag clicked.

So, we have /se/Home/About and /ge/Home/About. The user clicks on the German flag - how do we route them to the latter? And if they click on the Swedish flag - how do we route them to the former?

I've verified with [this blog](http://www.ryadel.com/en/setup-a-multi-language-website-using-asp-net-mvc/) but it doesn't address the actual issue with how to route into a certain language depending on the clicked flag image. I've also found [this blog](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/183/globalization-and-localization-with-razor-web-pages) but I simply don't understand how they do it. I see a bunch of calls to a DB so I suspect that it's not based on RESX files (and my understanding is that it's the proper way to go), although there's also some reference to *@TestResource*.

Right now I'm confused and uncertain. Any suggestions or clarifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a somewhat non-intuitive feature of MVC that makes this really easy. [MVC automatically reuses any route values](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1346) from the request. So all of your URLs will automatically "inherit" the culture - there is no need to specify it explicitly in `ActionLink`.

The one exception is during language selection. But you can take advantage of this same routing behavior to build a common header or footer in your `_Layout.cshtml`. Whatever route values the current page has will be inherited - all you need to do is specify controller, action, and culture.

```
@{ 
    var routeValues = this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values;
    var controller = routeValues["controller"] as string;
    var action = routeValues["action"] as string;
}
<ul>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Swedish", @action, @controller, new { lang = "se" }, new { rel = "alternate", hreflang = "se" })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("English", @action, @controller, new { lang = "en" }, new { rel = "alternate", hreflang = "en" })</li>
</ul>
```

As mentioned previously, all other links on the page will automatically be passed a culture from the current context, so they will automatically stay within the same culture. There is no reason to pass the culture explicitly in those cases.

```
@ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")
```

With the above link, if the current URL is `/Home/Contact`, the link that is generated will be `/Home/About`. If the current URL is `/en/Home/Contact`, the link will be generated as `/en/Home/About`.

Reference: [ASP.NET MVC 5 culture in route and url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764989/asp-net-mvc-5-culture-in-route-and-url)

Comment: Hmm... I recognize the insightfulness of your replies, so (now, that the sucking-up is delivered) I wonder if you mean that I've done way too much by implementing the special route and localization attribute. Are you saying that I only need to place a link with culture for the three languages somewhere in *_Layout.cshtml* and once the user click there (hence selecting the culture), it will live on? It **can't** be that easy... Can it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It is that easy. But, it does depend on there being a route to match the route value (which you have shown in your question). See my linked answer for how to handle the "default" language.

Comment: It's freaking awesome. It feels like a bug (that in this case is extremely helpful, though) but the stupid re-routing only handles the suffix **after** the second slash. That's great! Thanks.

Comment: But does this work for multiple concurent sessions of different languages?  Surely changing the global culture affects them all ?

Comment: The above code isn't dealing with the culture, it is simply building a hyperlink with the culture string in it. If you follow through to [ASP.NET MVC 5 culture in route and url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764989/asp-net-mvc-5-culture-in-route-and-url), there is a `CultureFilter` which sets the culture based on the URL. This culture is not global, it is associated with the current thread, and will not affect other users of the application.