# Convert Query string to Route Path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have an issue and cant seem to resolve it. I have a url, thats like:

```
myurl/?culture=fr
```

what I want is

```
myurl/fr
```

My Controller looks like :

```
public ActionResult Index(string culture = null)
```

and my routeConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Languages",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{culture}"
);
```

This results in the page isn't redirecting properly.
Any hints to solve it?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details? What are you seeing as a result when you try to redirect using the myurl/fr syntax?

Comment: I get: Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 5 culture in route and url](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32764989/181087)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give default Controller and action in your route if you are appending "fr" to the root of the URL(www.yourUrl.com/fr). like this :-

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Languages",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{culture}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
```

);

Replace "Home" with your default controller and "Index" with default action.

Comment: Can you explain more, What should be my routes.MapRoute be?

Comment: It doesnt works. it results in page not redirecting properly if used as myurl/Home/Index/fr and Server error if myurl/fr

Comment: is your Index action method in Home controller?

Comment: It is working fine at my end. Are you returning right view from action method? 
or put a break point on action method and check if your parameter have value? if it has value than there is something wrong with return statement in action method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116392/discussion-between-sombir-verma-and-saad-farooq).