# Setting custom MVC routes with fixed parts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have 2 controllers:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(string id) //id is category slug
        {
           if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
               id = "MainCategory";
           var model = getCategoryPageModel(id);
           return View(model);
        }
    }
public class PostController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(string id) //id is post slug
        {
          var model = getPostModel(id);
          return View(model);
        }
    }
```

And this is my route config:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            //angular route for admin section
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "AngularCatchAllRoute",
               url: "Admin/{*any}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index"}
               );

            //route which includes language
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultLocalized",
                url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                constraints: new { lang = @"(\w{2})|(\w{2}-\w{2})" },   // en or en-US
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
            );

            //do I need this one??
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
```

I want to have two types of custom routes:

www.mysite.xyz/categoryName - calls Home/Index/id with default language ('sr')
www.mysite.xyz/en/categoryName - calls Home/Index/id with language 'en'

www.mysite.xyz/Post/postID - calls Post/Index/id with default language('sr')
www.mysite.xyz/en/Post/postID - calls Post/Index/id with language 'en'

**My 'DefaultLocalized' route already works fine** with default and custom language route part, but my url has to contain all route parts: controller/action/id. I just want to simplyfy urls to be more readable to users.

Actually I made it work for post with 'lang' to be mandatory:
www.mysite.xyz/sr/Post/postID - but I want 'sr' to be default like in 'DefaultLocalized' route, there I don't have to set lang to be 'sr'...

I already have tried some answers from other similar questions but I did not make it work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 5 culture in route and url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764989/asp-net-mvc-5-culture-in-route-and-url)

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute routing as below:

```
[Route("~/{cate}")]
[Route("{lang}/{cate}")]
public IActionResult Index(string lang, string cate)
{
   return View();
}
```

That work for me with urls:

http://[host]/Mobile

http://[host]/en/Mobile

Hope this help!

Comment: I tried to avoid using 'lang' as action parameter, I folowed this post for multi-language site: http://www.ryadel.com/en/setup-a-multi-language-website-using-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: I'm not sure but that can be useful for you at here: http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx