# How to manually set the Culture during a ASP.NET Core MVC request?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, culture

I'm looking for something similar like the old behaviour of setting the Culture and *everything in the request after that* has that Culture.

Similar like ASP.NET 4.5:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture     = culture_info; 
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture   = culture_info;
```

When I do this right now, some code seems to be constantly resetting the Culture to English at various points in the MVC pipeline.

Why do I want that? Because I want to set the culture through my extended routing logic in a very large (and customizable) platform-type of web project.

The default RouteDataRequestCultureProvider doesn't seem to work at all - see explained here:

https://irensaltali.com/en/asp-net-core-mvc-localization-by-url-routedatarequestcultureprovider/

and

[Localization works when culture is set via QueryString but not when culture is in route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529593/localization-works-when-culture-is-set-via-querystring-but-not-when-culture-is-i)

I don't want to use the "hardcoded" url parsing that is being presented as a solution, because my routing logic is complicated - not *all* routes will have a culture defined in the same spot in the URL.

I tried setting this, but that also didn't work:

```
httpContext.Features.Set<IRequestCultureFeature>(new RequestCultureFeature(request_culture, new DummyProvider()));
```

**Is there any workaround for just *simply* setting the Culture for the rest of the request?**

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for simply setting the Culture for the rest of the request is to use default `QueryStringRequestCultureProvider`.

Here is the whole demo:

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

    services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
    //...
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    var supportedCultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("de"),
        new CultureInfo("fr"),
    };

    app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
    {
        DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
        // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
        SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
        // UI strings that we have localized.
        SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
    });

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Create Resource folder and add resource file as below:

[image]

Configure resource file like below:

`Controllers.HomeController.de.resx`

[image]

`Controllers.HomeController.fr.resx`

[image]

Reference:[Resource file naming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#resource-file-naming)

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<HomeController> _localizer;

    public HomeController(IStringLocalizer<HomeController> localizer)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = _localizer["Your Title"];
        return View();
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@ViewData["Title"]
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Rena, thanks for your very extended answer - even a GIF! :O For me it's a prerequisite that I can set the culture during routing - so between routing and actually creating the controller. I can't use the QueryString version.

Comment: Did you mean you want to add the culture to the route?

Comment: Yeah - during some rather complicated (xml based) own routing logic - I'm not using the default routing. But I even wat more freedom - I just want to say at a certain point in the request: from now on everything will be this culture during this request.

Comment: Could you share how did you configure your routing?And it seems you want to set the culture for one time and the other request would use this culture?And which location you want to add the culture to the route?

Comment: Hi @Rena - I'm sorry it's a large library-kind-of-project where I route by using a centralized xml file - I think it's a bit out of the scope of the question. Mainly I'm just looking for *control*. I just want to set Thread.CurrentCulture and hope it is being honored. As a lot of .NET Core is customizable I hope also this is.

Answer (score 1):

While I too can't find a way to set the request culture for the rest of the request you can use the CustomRequestCultureProvider and use your custom routing logic to get set the culture for the request

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(options =>
{
    options.AddSupportedUICultures(... set some cultures here...)
           .AddSupportedCultures(... and here...)
           .AddInitialRequestCultureProvider(new CustomRequestCultureProvider(async context =>
           {
               string cultureCode = await RunCustomRoutingAndGetCulture(context.Request);
               return new ProviderCultureResult(cultureCode);
           }));
});
```

If your custom logic does not require awaiting remove async and return with Task.FromResult

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution similar to the OP's question for setting a culture after the request. I needed to retrieve a culture string in a query string or a request header and @Stilgar's answer provided the solution I needed. Here's a working solution of his answer. It extracts a culture key/value pair in the query string. (The code to check the request header was left out.)

For a URL request `https://localhost:7181/?culture=fr`, the culture `fr-FR` is set. In the `OnPost` method, `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` returns `fr-FR`.

```
public void OnPost()
{
    // Display the current culture
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Current culture is " + Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.EnglishName);
}
```

`program.cs`

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(options =>
    {
        string defaultCulture = "en-US";
        string[] supportedCultures = new string[] { "fr-FR", defaultCulture };

        options.AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures)
            .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
            .AddInitialRequestCultureProvider(
                new CustomRequestCultureProvider(async context =>
                {
                    string? cultureCode =
                        await GetCultureFromRequest(context.Request, supportedCultures) ?? defaultCulture;
                    return new ProviderCultureResult(cultureCode);
                }));
    });

static Task<string?> GetCultureFromRequest(
    HttpRequest request, string[] supportedCultures)
{
    if (request.QueryString.Value is null ||
        !request.QueryString.Value.Contains("culture="))
    {
        return Task.FromResult<string?>(default);
    }

    string? cultureVal =
        request.Query.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Key == "culture").Value;

    if (cultureVal is null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cultureVal))
    {
        return Task.FromResult<string?>(default);
    }

    string? cultureEntry = supportedCultures
        .Where(c => c.Contains(cultureVal)).FirstOrDefault();

    return Task.FromResult(cultureEntry ?? default);
}
```

The above solution is the same as setting up a localization middleware found [here](https://damienbod.com/2017/11/01/shared-localization-in-asp-net-core-mvc):

`program.cs`

```
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    CultureInfo[] supportedCultures = new[]
     {
        new CultureInfo("fr"),
    };
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider());
});

IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> locOptions = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);
```