# Convert asp.net website from English to Arabic

Tags: asp.net, localization, translation, arabic

I have developed one ASP.NET website for my client and now he wants the website to translate from English to Arabic. Can anyone help me how to do this? Is there any ASP.NET class or function for this?

Comment: read about resource files.

Comment: @Afnan I dont know where to read resource file .Can you explain in detail

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: See [ASP.NET MVC 5 culture in route and url](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32764989)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Step 1:***

You need to first Add `App_LocalResources` Folder. As you have tagged `asp.net` so I am assuming it is Web Application. Right click your root directory and navigate to Add and then navigate to `Add ASP.NET Folder` and then navigate to `App_LocalResources`.

[image]

***Step 2:***

Once you have created the folder. Right click on it and add `Resource file`. For adding resource file right click at `App_LocalResources` and then navigate to Add and then navigate to `New Item` there you can Find `Resources File`.

[image]

***Step 3:***

If you have a page Named `Default`, than resource file name for English would be `Default.aspx.resx` for french would be `Default.aspx.fr.resx` for Arabic it would be `Default.aspx.ar.resx`. Remember every language will have separate file names.

[image]

***Step 4:***

Now lest suppose if you have label at Default page and it is like `<asp:Label ID="lblTest" Text="Test"></asp:Label>` then you need to add meta resource key for every element at page like this: `meta:resourcekey="lblTestResource1"`. Remember resource key name can be any thing which you like but ID with `Reosource1` is just a trend. so your label would be like: `<asp:Label ID="lblTest" Text="Test"`meta:resourcekey="lblTestResource1">`.

[image]

***Step 5:***

Now in next step you need to open resource files and you have to insert in string resource key names. You will insert `lblTestResource1.Text` in string and will insert `Test` in value and save.

***Step 6:***

Once you are done with this open `web.config` file and insert `<globalization uiCulture="ar" />` under  `<system.web>` section and you are done for Arabic.

[image]

***Note: For Arabic `uiCulture` is `ar`***

Comment: It is very helpful but i want to make one dropdown with 2 option (English,Arabic). So, the page should be translate based on user selection

Comment: @Rizvi Than you need to find out how on base of selection of drop down value you can change web config `uiCulture` value.

Comment: Thanks for your help and i got some idea as well from here.