# C# MVC Localization Issue with Image URLs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization

I need to build a c# MVC portal that is localized.

I have the following route defined:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "DefaultLocalized",
url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
constraints: new { lang = @"(\w{2})|(\w{2}-\w{2})" },   // en or en-US
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 
UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Also implemented a LocalizedControllerActivator.

All works great.

Defaults urls:

http://test

http://test/about
...

When language changed to German it routes to

http://test/de

http://test/de/about
...

that is great.

The issue I have is with images.

for the following line

```
<img src="media/images/backgrounds/bg.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" 
width="42">
```

it would resolve to http://test/de/media/images/backgrounds/aria_bg3.jpg

I would like to simply use

```
http://test/media/images/backgrounds/bg3.jpg
```

and ignore the language string all together

or I would like to have a different structure like

```
http://test/media/de/images/backgrounds/bg3.jpg
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Moz

Comment: See [ASP.NET MVC 5 culture in route and url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32839796/). The reason why the URL is being generated this way is because your constraint always matches this route when generating the URL (same as the other answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to prepend the src with a `/`. It will give you the base path.

So for example if `thats/a/test` is resolved under url `https://www.google.com/images`, the resulting URL will be `https://www.google.com/images/thats/a/test`, but when you use `/thats/a/test`, the resulting URL will be `https://www.google.com/thats/a/test`.

I think this would fix your problem.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you

Answer (score 1):

Use relative path to the root of your website.
Try to start your attribut "src" by "/", like this :

```
<img src="/media/images/backgrounds/bg.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```

An other solution is to use [html base tag](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_base.asp) in the head of your webpage, like this :

```
<head>
    <base href="http://test/" target="_blank">
</head>
```