# How to redirect Site for specific country users?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cultureinfo

I have a same website in two different languages, with two different domains, one in English and other in Turkish.

Whenever someone accesses my website (www.example.com) I want to redirect that user to `www.example.tr` if he is accessing that site from `TURKEY` else to .com if he is accesing my website `other` that TURKEY

**Q**: How do i achieve that in asp.net?

**Q**: What are the options available to achieve this?

**Q**: Do i have to make changes to IIS or in my CODE?

Comment: @JohnB, the question link you have provided is not answered and hence this question cannot be marked as duplicate of that one.

Comment: apologies - wrong link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764989/asp-net-mvc-5-culture-in-route-and-url#32839796

Comment: Maybe this helps:https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/aspnetcore-geo-location-from-ip-address/

Comment: Is there is anything we can do in IIS??

Comment: no - you can not just do it on IIS, except if you find some kind of extension - search on google to see if anyone exist - To know the country of your user and act, you need to programming....

Answer (score 0):

You can use ip geolocation service like "ipstack.com" to find the location of the visitor:
ipstack.com example for the Standard Lookup Endpoint using jQuery.ajax. (First register in free Plan and get your API Access Key)

```
// set endpoint and your access key
var ip = '134.201.250.155'
var access_key = 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY';

// get the API result via jQuery.ajax
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.ipstack.com/' + ip + '?access_key=' + access_key,   
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {

        // output the "capital" object inside "location"
        alert(json.location.capital);

    }
});
```

Now based on the answer you received, you can redirect the user to the website you want without any change in IIS.

```
if (countryCode == "Turkey")
  response.redirect("www.yoursite.tr");
else
  response.redirect("www.yoursite.com");
```

Comment: This is javascript code, the question is on asp.net, and not include javascript tags...

Comment: It's example from ipstack.com documentation. You can use this with HttpClient in asp.net.

Comment: Only if has tag it with javascript... now is ask for asp.net solution

Comment: It is important to show the way.

Comment: This is not the way - you show on a different language how you use a library. I vote to delete it !

Comment: I introduced a service in the first section and part of the documentation. The second section is actually a c#.