# ASP.NET MVC Routing with Areas & Languages not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a site with controllers and two other areas with the respective controllers for each. One of the controllers within the area has a language contraint code say en. By default it works perfectly fine. But when I try to use the `Route` specification in the controllers it is building the routes in misleading way.

The RouteConfig.cs file looks like below

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "DefaultWithLanguageAndOrg",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
          namespaces: new[] { "MyProj.Website.WebApp.Controllers" }

      );

    }
```

Part of Area registration file looks like below:-

```
   public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Test_default",
            "{lang}/Test/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { lang = new LanguageRouteConstraint() },
            new[] { "MyProj.Website.WebApp.Areas.Test.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

And controller looks like below:-

```
[RouteArea("Test")]
[RoutePrefix("certificate")]
public class CertificationsController : Controller
{

    [Route("Home")]
    public ActionResult Home()
    {
        return View();

    }
}
```

My expecation is to have the URL structure like `site/en/Test/certificate/Home` but I'm not able to add the prefix `en` before RouteArea.

Note:-

1. Tried adding en into the RouteArea like `[RouteArea("en/Test")]` it executes the action but expects the views folder to be moved inside en. That is not a proper solution, other routes without the Route specification will not work.
2. Tried adding Area and language contraint within the RoutePrefix like  `[RoutePrefix("{lang}/Test/certificate/Home")]`, it executes the action but not renders the view. It searches the view in the path like `~/Views/Certifications/Home.cshtml` where Area Test is missing, it should be like `~/Test/Views/Certifications/Home.cshtml`. And this format as well `[RoutePrefix("en/{area}/certificate")]` no luck.

Comment: See if this helps you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764989/asp-net-mvc-5-culture-in-route-and-url

Answer (score 1):

You can override the View() of the Controller

like -

```
protected override ViewResult View(string ViewName, string masterName, object model)
    {
        return PrepareView(ViewName, masterName, model);
    }

private ViewResult PrepareView(string ViewName, string masterName, object model)
    {
        renderview = base.View("~/Views/Shared/" + ViewName + ".cshtml", masterName, model); 
        return base.View(ViewName, masterName, model);
    }
```

This is just a example code, similar to this you can override the path using your languagecode.